# WinRT: PNG files are not showing transparent

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, png

I've got Metro app with main page that contains GridView.

```
    <Page
    x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ReqWriter8"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded" >

  <Page.Resources>
    <!-- Collection of items displayed by this page --> 
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="MyMenu"  Source="{Binding}"></CollectionViewSource>
  </Page.Resources>

  <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" >


    <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid -->
    <GridView 
            x:Name="itemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
            TabIndex="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Padding="116,136,116,46"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyMenu}}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
      <GridView.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
          <GradientStop Color="#FF1F4870" Offset="0"/>
          <GradientStop Color="#FBA0B9D3" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
      </GridView.Background>

      <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
          <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250" >
            <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
              <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" />
            </Border>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Transparent" >
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10" FontSize="12"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

The issue here is that PNG images are not transparent (although when I open them in Picture editor they are transparent)

I know there is attribute Window.AllowsTransparency = true attribute but it seems it does not apply for Metro App.
So how can I fix this ?

Comment: Hello.  Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The border background of your ItemTemplateis is using **ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush** as a background.

Just remove it and the issue will be resolved.

```
<Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" />
</Border>
```